# Is Windows (as in MS Windows) "it" or "them"

Tags: grammatical-number

As in "This is MS Windows, do you like it?" vs "This is MS Windows, do you like them?".

Or "My MS Windows crashed, what should I do to fix them?" vs "My MS Windows crashed, what should I do to fix it?".

Which one is correct?

Comment: MS Windows is the name of an operating system and is therefore singular

Comment: My operating system crashed. One doesn't usually name it when referring to its crashing....Operating system is singular, with or without the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "My MS Windows crashed, what should I do to fix **it**?"

MS Windows is the name for a **singular** instance of an operating system. If you had multiple instances of the operating system running and they all crashed, only then would you use the plural form.

In a similar way you could say,

> "I'm going to play billiards. I'll enjoy **it** more than fixing my
>   computer,"

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Windows is a group of several graphical operating system families, all of which are developed, marketed, and sold by Microsoft. (ref: Wikipedia)

So- MS Windows here is referred to as being singular, even though a closer view shows there are many different parts. That is on second sight however. these parts are plural.

I would follow the developper of the software and write and say MS Windows *is*.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the above, having worked in IT and related fields in a Windows environment, the operating system on a computer is a singular entity, as seen when you say to 'repair your copy of Windows' it is thought of as a single copy rather than a multitude or collection of things.

Answer (score 0):

What is Windows? Windows is the Operating System in my computer. So, it is singular. What is plural for Windows operating system? "Windows operating systems" You will never encounter "Windows are crashed". If you see "Windows are" then you should understand that it is an error.